# MySQL IN() function issue - using alpha-numeric values

Tags: mysql

I am trying to figure out some situation by using IN() function of mysql.
The problem is:
Fetch data by filter some column like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COL IN (val1,val2,val3....)
```

Its work on numbers values like ...`WHERE COL IN (01,02,03,04..)`
but its not work if the values include alpha letters like `(D01,D02,R01..)`, it will work if the values will be `("D01","D02",...)`

I would like to get some advice if someone already faced with this thing.

thanks.

Comment: The difference between column names, strings and numbers should be explained in the first page of any SQL manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COL IN (val1,val2,val3....)
```

MySQL recognizes any label (column labels or values within the rows) with alphanumerics as a char type.
Hence,

```
WHERE COL IN (01,02,03,04..)
```

01, 02.. being recognized integer type it will return values from your table.

```
(D01,D02,R01..)
```

Running this will return an error statement.
These are, as I earlier mentioned, char type and hence '' or " " must be used.

@Álvaro I agree.

I hope I have cleared your doubts, atleast to some extent.

Comment: thanks, I did some string replacing, exploding and join again and created a string that seperated like "D01","U0" and its work.